# Why no mention of penalized regression techniques in Applied Logistic Regression, 3rd edition, by Hosmer, Lemeshow, and Sturdivant?

Tags: regression, logistic, lasso, epidemiology

Just ordered this textbook, and Wow, the complete omission of this subject from an otherwise excellent reference on logistic regression is a bit surprising. The 2nd edition was published in 2000 - there's been a lot of research into penalized regression techniques since then: for example, the lasso and elastic net.

I know this text is aimed at epidemiologists and public health specialists. Have researchers in these fields ignored any developments that smack of data mining?

Comment: Of course you can't cover everything; but in the 2nd edition the authors devoted a large part of one chapter to post-hoc variable selection techniques, including stepwise & best-subset methods (though they noted they were going out of fashion), & from what I can see on Google Books the coverage hasn't changed much in the 3rd edition. These techniques smack of data mining just as much as LASSO & elastic net do - so I agree that it's a rather surprising omission, but don't have any theories about it.

Comment: Unless one of them has written or spoken about this (which I doubt), answers about why this decision was taken are likely to be largely speculation - highly plausible reasons might be given, but they'll almost certainly remain speculation.

Comment: @Scortchi - Yes the methods described in the variable selection chapter seem outdated. I'm still glad I bought the book, not as a sole source for all things logistic regression but as a complimentary resource to other textbooks.

Comment: @RobertF: An ideal complement to *Applied Logistic Regression* IMO would be [Harrell (2002), *Regression Modelling Strategies*](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-95232-1), in which penalized regression methods often take centre stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that there is a prejudice against anything that comes close to data mining, but there can also be good reasons for omitting this area. Without further information I would start with the assumption that there was a good reason. If you assume a good reason and there was actually a prejudice the debate starts as much more friendly and is likely to become much more productive than when you assume prejudice and there was actually a good reason.

Any textbook needs to make a selection on what it covers and what it does not cover. The fact that something has developed recently is on its own not a sufficient reason to include it. I use logistic regression a lot in my own research and I have never been in a situation where I needed the lasso or elastic nets. So if I were writing such a textbook, I would probably ignore that part too. This is not to say there is anything wrong with these techniques; they just weren't useful for the problems I wanted to solve.

Since different (sub-)disciplines tend to focus on different types of questions, it is not surprising that some techniques are less useful for that (sub-)discipline than others. This should translate to which topics are covered in textbooks aimed at different (sub-)disciplines.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful response Maarten. I get the impression the field of statistics is fracturing into many subfields which don't communicate with each other.